# Clone an git repo to an offline machine

Tags: linux, git, github, debian, shiny-server

I want to clone an git repo to an offline VM (Debian). I can ssh into the offline VM via my local machine (Mac) which has internet access. How can I clone a git repo to that offline VM?

Does simply scp the repo folder to the VM directory works? Like:

```
local_machine$ git clone https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server.git

local_machine$ scp ~/shiny-server VM_machine:

local_machine$ ssh VM_machine:

VM_machine$ mv ~/shiny-server ~/workspace
```

Please help.

Comment: @Oliver I tried it. Yet, since this repo is just part of the dependencies and will takes time to actually run the whole thing. I just want to know whether I was on the right track.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just `clone` the repository in the VM from your local machine:

```
VM_machine$ git clone local_machine:~/shiny-server ~/workspace
```

[Reference: The SSH Protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-SSH-Protocol)

Comment: I see your point. However, there is a two layer SSH I have to go through to get to my VM. Like: local_machine -> ssh VM_machine1 -> ssh VM_machine2. What should I do to clone to that second VM?

Comment: Maybe this?: `VM_machine2$ git clone VM_machine1:~/workspace ~/workspace`

Comment: Thanks! So, I run "local_machine$ git clone https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server.git" to clone the repo to my local first. Then, I run your first command as "VM_machine1$ git clone local_machine:~/shiny-server ~/workspace" to copy the repo to the "~/workspace" directory on machine1. Last, I run "VM_machine2$ git clone VM_machine1:~/workspace/shiny-server ~/workspace" to copy the repo again from machine1 to machine2's directory "~/workspace". Did I interpret it right?

Comment: Yes. That's a way to do it if you don't have access neither to **github.com** nor **local_machine** from **VM_machine2**.

Comment: This works technically! However, I don't have the root permission on machine1 and it doesn't have internet access as well. However, I can scp file through my local to machine2 via machine1. Is there any way I can scp a source file to machine2 and unpack it locally on machine2? Thanks so much for all the information:)